# How to remove a value from a collection if it has a duplicate

Tags: java, collections, duplicates

Hello i have a collection and i want to remove a value from my collection if it has a duplicate.
If my value have a duplicate i want remove my value and the duplicate

Here is the declaration of my collection:

```
Collection<item> result = new Vector<item>();
```

I completed my collection via SQL queries

Comment: Simple.. Use `Set<item>`.. it will take care of duplicate.

Comment: it will take care of duplicate but it take care my value and his duplicate ?

Comment: Have you ever considered answering other's questions? 82 questions, 0 Answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If my value have a duplicate i want remove my value and the duplicate

Here is how to do it:

```
1. Create a dictionary in which the key is an item, and the value is an int.
2. Enumerate the items in your collection. For each item:
   2.1. If the item is already in the dictionary, get the value, increment it,
        and put it back in the dictionary. Otherwise, put the item in the 
        dictionary with a value of 1.
3. Enumerate the items in your dictionary. For each item:
   3.1  Get the corresponding value of the item from the dictionary, and if 
        it is greater than 1, remove all occurrences of that item from the 
        collection.
```

Of course, in order for this to work, your 'item' must have value semantics, not object semantics. In practice this means that it must have an Equals() method as well as a GetHashCode() method which take into consideration the contents of the object, not the object reference.

Answer (score 2):

`Set`'s works as a Mathematical Collection, so it doesn't allow duplicates in it's nature.

In practice, everytime you `.add()` and Item to it, it checks (via `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`) if that Item is already in your `Set`. It ignores it if it does.

Comment: Your Collection if of some Complex type (like "Person"), right? If it does, you could consider writing in it's Class the `.equals()` method.

Comment: You can add all the elements of your list to a Set.  BTW, I wouldn't use Vector, its unlikely to be the best choice of List.

Comment: @EvertonAgner and `hashCode()` method.

Comment: @Mercer : just do this: `Set<item> set = new HashSet<item>(result);`.  Now in set there will be no duplicates. All duplicates will be removed based on `.equals` and `.hashCode` method of `item` class.

Comment: The OP is saying that he needs to remove ALL occurrences of duplicate items; this means the item and its duplicate. You cannot use a SET for this. Besides, if the problem was just removing the duplicates, then he could have used a DISTINCT in the SQL query and we would never have had this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a `Set` if you don't want duplicates.